# Which of the following is the correct output for the program given below?

Tags: c, pointers

**if the machine is 32bit little-endianess and the  sizeof(int) is 4 byte.**

Given the following program:

```
 line1:  #include<stdio.h>
 line2:  {
 line3:      int arr[3]={2,3,4};
 line4:      char *p;
 line5:      p=(char*)arr;
 line6:      printf("%d",*p);
 line7:      p=p+1;
 line8:      printf("%d\n",*p);
 line9:      return 0;
         }
```

What is the expected output?

`A`: 2 3

`B`: 2 0

`C`: 1 0

`D`: garbage value

one thing that bothering me the casting of the integer pointer to an character pointer.

1. How important the casting is?
2. What is the compiler doing at line 5? (`p = (char *) arr;`)
3. What is happening at line 7? (`p = p + 1`)
4. If the output is `20` then how the `0` is being printed out?

Comment: @EricJ. actually i compiled it on my machine and got 2 0 as the output?

Comment: compile it on a SPARC or other big-endian machine, and you should get `00`, though - the behavior of this code is platform and compiler dependent.

Comment: This question makes no sense as neither the endianess nor the compiler nor `sizeof(int)` is mentioned.

Comment: It is really bad style just to copy your assignment here, without any attempt of a solution or mentioning where you got stuck. Voting to close.

Comment: @JensGustedt: sir actually I'm not an expert C programmer.I know that this is a silly question.please don't down vote it.I got stuck in the understanding of the steps what I mentioned there.

Comment: If you don't have any idea to share on that question, you lack information that your teacher should have provided. It makes no sense at all that others solve your homework here for you.

Comment: @JensGustedt: ok i would pay heed on your notice .but please don't down vote it.

Comment: @Krishna - This might work on some machines and give some results (or not). Language-wise it is not allowed, so it is pretty uninteresting. Another vote to close.

Comment: @krishnaChandra, I didn't downvote it (wasn't me) I voted to close it, which is a different thing on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.important of casting:-
  char *p;
   this line declare a pointer to a character.That means its property is it can de-reference
   only one byte at a time,and also displacement are one one byte.

p=(char*)arr;
2.   type casting to char * is only for avoid warning by compiler nothing else.
   If you don't then also same behavior.

1. as pointer to a character as I already write above p=p+1 point to next byte
2. printf("%d\n",*p);
   %d is formatting the value to decimal integer so decimal format shown
   here *p used and as per its property it can de-reference only one byte.So now memory organisation comes into picture.
   that is your machine follows little endian/LSB first or big endian/MSB first

   as per your ans your machine follow little endian.So first time your ans is 0.
   Then next byte must be zero so output is 0.
   in binary:
   2 represented as 00-00-00-02(byte wise representation)
   but in memory it stores like
   02-00-00-00 four bytes like this

   in first memory byte 02
   and in 2nd memory byte 00

Answer (score 1):

1. `(D)`, or compiler specific, as `sizeof(int)` (as well as endianness) is platform-dependent.

> How important the casting is?

Casting, as a whole is an integral (pun unintended) part of the C language.

> and what the compilar would do in line number5?

It takes the address of the first element of `arr` and puts it in `p`.

> and after line number 5 whats going on line number7?

It increments the pointer so it points to the next `char` from that memory address.

> and if the output is 2 0 then how the 0 is being printed by the compiler?

This is a combination of endanness and `sizeof(int)`. Without the specs of your machine, there isn't much else I can do to explain.

However, assuming little endian and `sizeof(int) == 4`, we can see the following:

```
// lets mark these memory regions: |A|B|C|D|
int i = 2; // represented as      0x02000000
char *ptr = (char *) &i; // now ptr points to 0x02 (A) 
printf("%d\n", *ptr); // prints '2', because ptr points to 0x02 (A) 
ptr++; // increment ptr, ptr now points to 0x00 (B)
printf("%d\n", *ptr); // prints '0', because ptr points to 0x00 (B)
```

Comment: I appreciate your all answer except the last one why the zero(0) is being printed by the compiler. it could be more emphasized

Comment: @krishnaChandra Because in memory (little endian), `2` is represented as  `0x0200`, and the first time you print the  pointer, it results in `2` (0x02). when you increment the pointer, you get the next byte, `0x00` printed out.

Answer (score 1):

(E) none of the above

However, provided that (a) you are on a little-endian machine (e.g. x86), and (b) `sizeof(int) >= 2`, this should print "20" (no space is printed between the two).

a) the casting is "necessary" to read the array one byte at a time instead of as a series of `int`s

b) this is just coercing the address of the first `int` into a pointer to `char`

c) increment the address stored in `p` by `sizeof(char)` (which is 1)

d) the second byte of the machine representation of the `int` is printed by line 8